# How to send mail to multiple recipients at once in Strapi?

Tags: email, strapi, amazon-ses

The following code block from strapi [documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/email) sends mail to one recipient at a time.

```
  await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
    to: 'mail@example.com',
    from: 'your verified email address', //e.g. single sender verification in SendGrid
    cc: 'valid email address',
    bcc: 'valid email address',
    replyTo: 'valid email address',
    subject: 'The Strapi Email plugin worked successfully',
    text: 'Hello world!',
    html: 'Hello world!',
  }),
```

How can I send it to multiple recipients at once?

I tried the below code block.
 `to: 'mail1@example.com,mail2@example.com',`

I am getting illegal address error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array in the `to:` field instead of sending directly.

For example:

```
await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
    to: ['mail@example.com','mail2@example.com',''mail3@example.com'],
    from: 'your verified email address', //e.g. single sender verification in SendGridenter code here
    cc: 'valid email address',
    bcc: 'valid email address',
    replyTo: 'valid email address',
    subject: 'The Strapi Email plugin worked successfully',
    text: 'Hello world!',
    html: 'Hello world!',
  }),
```